# Dynamic jquery AJAX upload form with text and file fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a dynamic form wherein a single item has a file, text and select html input types and number of items can be dynamic. The problem is when doing AJAX using jquery, the Form wont serialize for the file input type. Please suggest any technique to do it. My code is below:

```
<form id="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="divMain"></div>
    <div>
        <button id="Upload" type="button" value="Upload"><span>Upload</span></button>
        <input id="Add" type="button" value="Add" />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="status"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;

    AddElements(); //add first element

    $("#Add").click(function () {
        AddElements();
    });

    function AddElements() {
        counter++;

        $("#divMain").append("<div><input id='Browse" + counter + "' name='Browse[]' type='file' value='Browse' data-target='#Name" + counter + "' />" +
                                  "<input id='Name" + counter + "' name='Name[]' type='text'/>" +
                                    "<select id='Type" + counter + "' name='Type[]'>" +
                                        "<option>Option1</option>" +
                                        "<option>Option2</option>" +
                                    "</select></div>");

        $("#Browse" + counter + "").change(function () {
            var filename = $(this).val();
            var textbox = $($(this).attr("data-target"));

            var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
            var b = filename.lastIndexOf(".");

            if ((b == -1) | (b < lastIndex))
                filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
            else
                filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1, b - lastIndex - 1);

            textbox.val(filename);
        });
    }

    $("#Upload").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#status").html('Uploading....');

        var ajaxData = $("#Form1").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "AjaxPostDemo.aspx",
            type: "POST",
            data: ajaxData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#status").html("success: " + data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $("#status").html("error: " + result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your To script It Will Definately Work. :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var counter = 0;
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    AddElements(); //add first element

                    $("#Add").click(function () {
                        AddElements();
                    });

                    function AddElements() {
                        counter++;

                        $("#divMain").append("<div><input id='Browse" + counter + "' name='Browse[]' type='file' value='Browse' data-target='#Name" + counter + "' />" +
                                      "<input id='Name" + counter + "' name='Name[]' type='text'/>" +
                                        "<select id='Type" + counter + "' name='Type[]'>" +
                                            "<option>Option1</option>" +
                                            "<option>Option2</option>" +
                                        "</select></div>");

                        $("#Browse" + counter + "").change(function () {
                            var filename = $(this).val();
                            var textbox = $($(this).attr("data-target"));

                            var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
                            var b = filename.lastIndexOf(".");

                            if ((b == -1) | (b < lastIndex))
                                filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
                            else
                                filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1, b - lastIndex - 1);

                            textbox.val(filename);
                        });
                    }
                });
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#Upload").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        $("#status").html('Uploading....');

                        var ajaxData = $("#Form1").serialize();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "AjaxPostDemo.aspx",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: ajaxData,
                            cache: false,
                            processData: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                $("#status").html("success: " + data);
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                $("#status").html("error: " + result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

**Second Option**
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/multi/

Prefer This It will Uploaded Multifiles on one time with great UI. :-)

Comment: the changes code suggested had no different behavior. The issue is the file is not getting uploaded while other input elements are posted to the server. If the form is submitted normally (without ajax) then it works as intended. But, with ajax, the form is not serialized with the file data.